# Top 3 Preferred shops’ shopid that have the largest number of unique products

Tags: pandas

in answer to a question like "**Top 3 Preferred shops’ shopid that have the largest number of unique products**", I used the following logic:

1. ## check the values

data['is_preferred'].value_counts()

output:
0    440820
1     23613
Name: is_preferred, dtype: int64

2. ## number of preferred shops

data.query('is_preferred == 1')['shopid'].nunique()

output:
533

3. ## get the top 3

preferred_shops.nlargest(3, 'itemid')

output:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'nlargest'

I am stuck in here. Can someone help to take a look? Thank you! I use pandas.

my data look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNJVl.jpg)

Comment: atleast post your dataframe. What is `preferred_shops`?

Comment: is_preferred - 1 indicates the product is sold by a preferred shop